# How to grant a user ability to edit the pricebook he sees?

Tags: permission-sets, pricebook, owd

My OWD for pricebook is No Access, this gives me the ability to restrict users to the pricebook I want them to see.

I want to give a user the ability to edit the pricebook entries he sees.

If I give the "Edit" permission, than he gets the "Manage Pricebook" link, but he than gets access to all pricebooks - I want him to view/edit only the pricebooks that are shared to him.

[image]

What should be the permission sets? or how can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you have Record Types for each or your different Price Books?

Comment: No. Single record type